# Is there and R fucntion to mutate a variable on multiple columns conditions using If else or

Tags: if-statement

I am trying to create a variable in my data based on following conditions:

```
x y Z S T G
1 0 1 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1

if x=1 then 1, 
if y=1 then 2 if s=1 then 3, 
if t=1 then 4 if G=1 then 5 if X==y==z==1 then 6 and so on.
```

Please tell me how can i write this using if else

Answer (score 0):

Using if else?
You can calculate it without if else:

```
v <- 1:6
# this vector should give each column a the value
# 1 2 3 ... 6

# the most tedious part is to get your notes into a the R terminal
# as an R matrix.

# I used the fact that the string in R can span multiple lines:

s <- "x y Z S T G
1 0 1 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1"
# it looks like this:

s
## [1] "x y Z S T G\n1 0 1 0 1 0\n1 0 0 0 0 0 \n1 1 1 0 0 0 \n1 1 1 1 1 1"

# after trying long around with the base R functions
# which led to errors and diverse problems, I found the most elegant way
# to transform this string into a matrix-like tabular form
# is to use tidyverse's read_delim().
# install.packages("tidyverse")

# load tidyverse:
require(tidyverse) # or: library(tidyverse)

tb <- read_delim(s, delim=" ") ## it complains about parsing failues, but
tb
# A tibble: 4 x 6
      x     y     Z     S     T     G
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     1     0     1     0
2     1     0     0     0     0     0
3     1     1     1     0     0     0
4     1     1     1     1     1     1
# so it is read correctly in!



# what you want to do actually is
# to multiply each row with `v` and sum this result:

tb[1, ]
# A tibble: 1 x 6
      x     y     Z     S     T     G
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     1     0     1     0

# you do:

v * tb[1, ]

  x y Z S T G
1 1 0 3 0 5 0

# if you build sum with this, then you get your desired numbers

sum(v * tb[1, ])
## [1] 9


# row-wise manipulation of matrix/data.frame/tibbles you do by 
apply(tb, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(row) v * row)
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
x    1    1    1    1
y    0    0    2    2
Z    3    0    3    3
S    0    0    0    4
T    5    0    0    5
G    0    0    0    6

# very often such functions flip the results, so flip it back 
# by the transpose function `t()`:
t(apply(tb, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(row) v * row))
     x y Z S T G
[1,] 1 0 3 0 5 0
[2,] 1 0 0 0 0 0
[3,] 1 2 3 0 0 0
[4,] 1 2 3 4 5 6

# to get directly the sum by row, do:
apply(tb, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(row) sum(v * row))
## [1]  9  1  6 21

# these are the values you wanted, isn't it?

# I see now, that 

tb * v    # by using vectorization of R

     x y Z S T G
[1,] 1 0 3 0 5 0
[2,] 1 0 0 0 0 0
[3,] 1 2 3 0 0 0
[4,] 1 2 3 4 5 6

# therfore the rowSums are:

rowSums(tb * v)
## [1]  9  1  6 21
```

So this is the usual (messy) way how one often gets to the solution.

At the end, it boils down to this (and usually you find in Stack Overflow short answers like):

#### Short answer

```
require(tidyverse)

s <- "x y Z S T G
1 0 1 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1"

tb <- read_delim(s, delim=" ")
rowSums(tb * v)
```

And this is the beauty of R: If you know exactly what to do, it is just 1-3 lines of code (or a little more) ...